# PHP variable as Javascript variable name

Tags: javascript, php

I know this kind of post is frequently found on internet. But my problem is a little bit more dificult and I did not find an answer.

I want to make an associative array in Javascript in a loop with a variable name. 
($JJ = table of object)
($JJ->getResto($DB,$acad) allows me to recover my database datas)

```
$JJ = new RestaU();  
$JJ = $JJ->getResto($DB,$acad);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($JJ)-1; $i++) {
        //Datas recovering
        $lat = $JJ[$i]->loc_lat;
        $long = $JJ[$i]->loc_long;
        $name = $JJ[$i]->nom;
        $ville = $JJ[$i]->ville;

        //String treatment to avoid spaces
        $ville = str_replace(" ","",$ville);
        $name = str_replace(" ","",$name);

echo <<< SC
    <script>
            //here $ville will contain an google map object associated to the ville name.
            //It means that I need to change it for each "for" loop.

            var $ville = new Object();

            //that is why here I need to have $ville["name"] to generate a table for each city 
            //and have an access to it later.
            $ville+["name"] = new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$long);
            console.log(string2);
    </script>
SC;
```

My problem is, I can not find the solution to right for example ville1["name"]. Each time the code is not "interpreted" it means I can have the string but it does not create my array.

Thank you a lot for all your ideas!

**SOLUTION IN COMMENT.** 
I used that : 
var string = "$ville";
window[string]["name"] = "blabla";

It works really well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Not the duplicate if you read the whole topic :)

Comment: And the problem is that your JS can't read PHP variables? or...?

Comment: @Martijn really sorry I did a duplicate? I did not read the answer to it.. I will read the topic one more time. Thanks

Comment: @devJunk : I can not find how I can create the tables with a name which can change. Because I need to use table["attribute"], when I concatenate I do not have tables made. (It is difficult to be clear, sorry).

Comment: You want the name of the JS Variable to be generated by PHP?

Comment: What is the "+" in $ville+['name'] ?

Comment: I find the solution : var $acad = new Object();
               var string1 = "$acad";
               window[string1]["$name"] = new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$long);

It works perfectly. I will generate an array with a name that I can change in a loop. 

Thank you all for your time spent on it.

Comment: @devJunk : The + was to explain that I want to concatenate the string of $ville with ["name"] to form ville["name"] usable to make an associative array. I did it : string1 = "$ville". Then window[string]["name"] and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

php is server language and javascript is clint browser language!
in fact you can't share variables!
But you can print variables to javascript code like:

```
<script>
  var myvar = '<?php echo $myvar; ?>';
</script>
```

if you want to send variables from javascript to php you must use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)
for array

```
<script>
    <?php
    $array = array('index1'=>'hellow World!','index2'=>'Iran haven`t nuclear bomb');
    echo 'var arryname = new Array();';
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
      echo "\n arryname['{$key}'] = '{$val}';";
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer @M.Eskandari. //

If I do : 
var myvar = '<?php echo $myvar; ?>';

Can I use later : 
myvar["att.1"]? It will work? I try.

Comment: You should print all indexes in javascript! i'll edit Answer and add code for print array from php to JS!

Comment: No, it does not word. When I try to do console.log(myvar["att.1"]) I have "undefined" in the console. It means the table is not created I think.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. I am on it to try to understand this.

Comment: I am trying it and sure I will do accept if it works!

Comment: I do not know why my php code is not interpreted. I have exactly the same code written in the console... Normaly I am supposed to have the RESTULT of this code, no @M.Eskandari?

Comment: `<script>` and Html tags must writing out of `<?php ?>` tag!!! you can test my code at blank php page and see resualt!

Comment: Yes, we are agree about this point. But I still not have the code executed. For instance, I write <?php var_dump(variable) ?> into my <scrip> balises and I do not have the variable printed.